# How do you determine if its an improper node of a proper node?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

This is my example but your welcome to elaborate if you have better examples. Suppose we have a system of differential equations

$$\frac{dR}{dt}=aJ \\
\frac{dJ}{dt}=bR$$

s.t. $a,b \gt 0$. I've determined that the eigenvalues are equal and are greater than zero by using the Jacobian $(A)$ and evaluating the determinant, $\det(A-r \mathbb{I})$, to get the characteristic equation. Thus we have an unstable improper or proper node. How would you determine if its an improper or a proper node from the given differential equations? I know it has to do something with having two independent eigenvectors or one independent eigenvector.

Comment: Please use latex for maths text.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And $\tau^{2} = 4 \delta \implies \Delta = 0 \implies$ only one eigenvalue $\implies$ improper node.

Comment: @Mattos when writing in latex, do you just input the latex formula onto the writing box? ex. $a\lt b$. Also why does $r^2 \eq 4\delta$ imply the discriminant is equal to 0?  isn't r denoted as an eigenvalue? and what is delta? Doesn't having an improper node and a proper node imply that you have one eigenvalue by definition?

Comment: @Mattos nevermind about the latex except I don't know how to fix the $\eq$ sign

Comment: For the equals sign just use the equals symbol on your keyboard. Also, the discriminant $\Delta$ _is_ $\tau^{2} - 4\delta$ (think about the quadratic formula) ie $\Delta = \tau^{2} - 4\delta \therefore \Delta = 0 \implies \tau^{2} - 4\delta = 0 \implies \tau^{2} = 4\delta$. And my $\tau$ _is not_ your $r$, $\tau$ is the trace , which is the sum of the diagonals of your matrix.